# Filtering by higher nodes attributes linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to serialize and insert a new created object into a specific child node of an `XDocument`. I've managed to accomplish this but my code seems smelly.

How can I test against a higher nodes attribute value without chaining through the `Parent` property like I have done below?

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);

var elements = (
    from doc in xdoc.Descendants("Unit")
    where doc.Parent.Parent.Attribute("name").Value == _UnitTypeName &&
    doc.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Attribute("name").Value == _UnitCategoryN
    doc.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Attribute("name").Value == 
    select doc
    );

foreach (var element in elements)
{
    Unit unit =
        new Unit
        {
            Armour = _Armour,
            Attacks = _Attacks,
            BallisticSkill = _BallisticSkill,
            Composition = _Composition,
            DedicatedTransport = _DedicatedTransport,
            Initiative = _Initiative,
            Leadership = _Leadership,
            Options = _Options,
            SaveThrow = _SaveThrow,
            SpecialRules = _SpecialRules,
            Strength = _Strength,
            Toughness = _Toughness,
            UnitName = _UnitName,
            Weapons = _Weapons,
            WeaponSkill = _WeaponSkill,
            Wounds = _Wounds,
            Points = _Points
        };

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Unit));
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        serializer.Serialize(stream, unit, ns);
        stream.Position = 0;

        //using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
        //{
        //    XElement xe = XElement.Load(reader);
        XElement xe = XElement.Load(@"C:\Test\tempfile.xml"); // For some reason loading via MemoryStream messes with xml formatting
        element.AddBeforeSelf(xe);
        //}
    }
    break;
}
xdoc.Save(path);
```

This is the structure of the XML Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfArmy>
  <Army name="Tyranid">
    <unit-category>
      <UnitCategory name="Troops">
        <unit-type>
          <UnitType name="Infantry">
            <unit>
              <Unit points="5" name="Hornmagant" composition="20" weapon-skill="3" ballistic-skill="100" strength="3" toughness="4" wounds="1" initiative="3" attacks="3" leadership="5" saving-throw="6+" armour="Chitin" weapons="Many" special-rules="None" dedicated-transport="No" options="8">
                <Amount>0</Amount>
              </Unit>
              <Unit points="5" name="Termagant" composition="20" weapon-skill="3" ballistic-skill="100" strength="3" toughness="4" wounds="1" initiative="3" attacks="3" leadership="5" saving-throw="6+" armour="Chitin" weapons="Many" special-rules="None" dedicated-transport="No" options="8">
                <Amount>0</Amount>
              </Unit>
            </unit>
          </UnitType>
        </unit-type>
      </UnitCategory>
    </unit-category>
  </Army>
</ArrayOfArmy>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[compound from clauses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383978.aspx)**, which is similar to using nested `foreach` loops:

```
var elements = (
    from army in xdoc.Descendants("Army")
    where army.Attribute("name").Value == _ArmyName
    from unitCategory in army.Descendants("UnitCategory")
    where unitCategory.Attribute("name").Value == _UnitCategoryName
    from unitType in unitCategory.Descendants("UnitType")
    where unitType.Attribute("name").Value == _UnitTypeName
    from unit in unitType.Descendants("Unit")
    select unit
    );
```

Note: the method syntax equivalent is **[SelectMany()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx)**.

Comment: Thanks! Using the compound for clauses with the `where` filter to achieve the same result, much more readable!

Comment: @Amicable: I'm glad you got what you needed from my answer.  To avoid confusing future readers, I want to make sure my query matches your original one.  Is my edited answer what your new query looks like?  I'm not too experienced with XML, and the upper and lower case names threw me off.

Comment: The nodes with the hyphen don't have attributes so I'd get a null reference querying their names. Those nodes represent the serialized `List<T>`s.
I had to stick a couple random `/` in to make character limit for edit.